# how to configure the new alerts in azure monitor using ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, alerts

I am working on Azure Resource Manager Templates, Currently I created ARM templates for various azure resources like virtual machine, SQL Server, Service Bus and Web app etc...

But, for that I want to configure the azure alerts in monitor using ARM template not through the azure portal.

I followed below links to configure the new alerts experience in azure monitor:

1. [The next generation of Azure Alerts has arrived](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-next-generation-of-azure-alerts-has-arrived/)
2. [The new alerts experience in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-unified-alerts)
3. [Create, view, and manage alerts using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-alerts-unified-usage)

Can anyone suggest me how to configure the new alerts in azure monitor using ARM templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-create-metric-alerts-with-templates) shows how you can use an Azure Resource Manager template to configure newer metric alerts in Azure Monitor. Resource Manager templates enable you to programmatically set up alerts in a consistent and reproducible way across your environments. Newer metric alerts are currently available on this set of resource types.

Comment: Thanks Zahid, But I want to create alert for application insights with signal type as `Custom log search`, in that how to write the custom query like `traces 
| where timestamp > now() | where message contains "Success" 
` using ARM template.

Comment: I resolved my above problem mentioned in the comment by following this [Managing log alert on Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-alerts-unified-log-template)